# Instantiated 2D text doesn't show up in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, instantiation

Excuse me for any grammatical errors. (I know that there are many questions like this here, but I haven't found a solution yet).

I'm trying to instantiate a 2d object with a 2d text, the problem here is that the text is invisible when instantiated. Yes, I know that I have to set a canvas as parent of it but it is still not working...
Code:

```
Instantiate(levelAsteroid, new Vector3(-7, 2.25f, 0), Quaternion.identity, 
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Canvas").transform);
```

Unity hierarchy, when the object is instantiated:

[image: Hierarchy]

Canvas settings:

[image: canvas]

Update:
I think I found the problem.
If I just instantiate the object, it works fine, the text is visible, but if I try to change the text from the script, the text becomes corrupt, after that the text won't never show up not even if I put the object in the canvas manually.

**FIXED:**
The problem seems to be the way I used to change the text..
Before, I used to instantiate the object and change the text from a script attached to the GameController, now I change the text from a script attached to the object that has the text as child.

Before:
(Script attached to the GameController):

```
public GameObject exampleOfObj;
void instantiateObj(){
        object = Instantiate(exampleOfObj, new Vector3(-800, 300f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        object.transform.SetParent (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Canvas").transform, false);
        objectText.SetText ("Text: " + value);
}
```

I simply removed the call to the "SetText" method and I have put this into the script that is attached to the object that I'm instantiating.
I found a solution but I don't understand why it was a problem.

Comment: Just pass `false`to the Instantiate function

Comment: I have already done it but nothing changed.. and this question is not a duplicate

Comment: Do you have any Animator component on your Text object?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to figure out your issue without additional information. Possible solution is use Transform.SetParent method with worldPositionStays parameter set to false instead of instantiating on parent transform. You can find troubleshooting of similar issues in [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html). See **Instantiating the UI element** section.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but it is the same..
Which additional informations can I give you?

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly as you did and it is showing the text. My canvas settings are :

Render Mode : Scale Space - Camera (Camera Attached)
UI Scale Mode : Scale With Screen Size
Reference Resolution : 1920 x 1440
Match = 0.5

Also make sure when you put the object in the canvas manually, it is also showing the text.

Comment: I'm really confused... When I'm creating the prefab the text is showing up whithout any problems: https://i.imgur.com/2CK45vR.png when I save it as prefab, it is still perfectly working, if I put the prefab manually in the canvas it works fine but when I instantiate it from a script, the FIRST  time it works fine, after the first time the prefab is like corrupted, the text is not showing up anymore, not even if I put it manually in the canvas.. It makes no sense..

Comment: If I just instantiate the object, it works fine, the text is visible, but if I try to change the text from the script, the text becomes corrupt, after that the text won't never show up not even if I put the object in the canvas manually.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BRDFCNZ Here is my code (Same as your code) it is attached to the camera and it is working fine and when i press u it is changing the text without any problem. Probably you are missing a very little thing but glad you fixed your problem.